# I have Two Column in a Table like brand and product so how I prevent same product insert in same brand?

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have two column one is brand and other is product and there is a data like samsung and galaxy j8.
If I insert again samsung and galaxy j8 it shows me error.
So how to do this ?

Comment: I suppose to ask question, are you doing `INSERT INTO`? If yes, try using `INSERT IGNORE INTO` instead.

Comment: Could you please explain it, I am new to mysql so I am confused?

Comment: Well, first of all, you need to specify how do you insert the data. It's better if you have example provided into your question. Like a table structure or the code you've tried to execute your insert and the error message it returns. This will help us to help you efficiently. Now, your question is tagged with mysql and php so we don't really know your error is coming from where.. ;)

Comment: I think the question is a simple as "what is a primary key" and thus should be closed or redirected. Also title and question seem to contradict.

Answer (score 0):

From the database itself prevent duplicate insertion  of two column use [`constrain`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) like this

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT constrain_name UNIQUE (brand,product);
```

Comment: How can I  do this in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: copy paste this sql code on your respect database sql tab https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GhEw.png and change respect table name and column name